# Regular expression for finding with start and ending with one quote or mutiple quotes

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to find words that are start and end with one or more specific start symbols. For example:

**:this:  or 
::test:: or ::test: or :test:: or ::test::: or :test::::: or ::::this: or ::this:::: or :::::this:**

A word that starts with less than two **:** or ends with less than two **:**  are the words that I am looking for. Here is the pattern I tried:

```
public static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(":{1,2}.*:{1,2}", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

It is not working for all cases. It fails for some cases like this one:

**:::::amazing:::**

It is worth noting that a word that starts with greater than or equal to two **:** or ends with greater than or equal to three **:** is also a correct entry.

Comment: #1: Please use inline code (back-ticks) on StackOverflow when posting questions like this; otherwise it's impossible to distinguish two `'` characters from one `"` character in the non-code font.  #2: Why is there a back-quote in your pattern, when I don't see any in your examples?

Comment: sorry . actually pattern is inline (back ticks only) but as stackoverflow has that feature question box .

Comment: I can appreciate that it's hard to show a back tick in StackOverflow.  But if you're going to replace it with another character, *please add something to the question to let us know what you're doing*.  **We cannot read minds.**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the back-quote in your pattern is a mistake, and it's supposed to be a regular quote:

```
public static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("'{1,2}.*'{1,2}", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

there are two problems.

(1) `.` matches any character, including a quote mark.  Therefore you can't really put a limit on the number of quote marks, since extra quote marks can be picked up by the dot.  Use `[^']` which matches any character that isn't a quote.

(2) Assuming #1 is fixed, the pattern matches if the word starts with 1 or 2 quote marks *and* ends with 1 or 2 quote marks.  To achieve an "or", you will need two patterns separated by `|`: one for words that start with 1 or 2 quote marks and end with any positive number of quote marks, and another for words that start with any positive number of quote marks and end with 1 or 2 quote marks.

This is assuming I understand the question correctly.

**Edit:** I answered this before the quote marks and the back-quote in the question were changed to colons.  Replace "quote marks" with "colon" in my answer accordingly.  Please be careful about making such substantial changes to questions that they could make correct answers look wrong.

**Edit 2:** It seems that the character is actually supposed to be a back-quote.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure that I understand your reuirement but you can try:

```
public static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[\"']+(.*?)[\"']+", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

That expression captures a word between 2 sequences of quotes (at least one quote in each sequence).